# C# WCF Service The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'RealTimeTransaction'

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, https, soap1.2

I have a WCF  service that required soap 1.2 and run on https. The service is based in the "http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/" WSDL. I call the service using SoapUI and it work fine. Then I try to use a standard client the is based in the follogin WSDL "http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/" and it display the error:
The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'RealTimeTransaction'.
I verify and if in SoapUi under the WS-A option the "Enable WS-A addressing is check, if I remove the option and run the service it return the same error: The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'RealTimeTransaction'. This make me think that the problem is that the standard client that I,m using for tests is not setting the WS-A Addressing option.

Is there a way in my service that I can configure my service to use Soap1.2 run over https and do not requeried the Enable WS-A addressing option?

I try a custome biding with no succes.

This is my binding

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
name="CORESoapBinding" bindingName="CORESoapBinding" 
bindingNamespace="http://www.caqh.org/SOAP/WSDL/"
contract="CORE.Interfaces.CORETransactions" />
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" 
contract="IMetadataExchange" /> 
</service>
</services>
<protocolMapping>
<remove scheme="http" />
<add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding" />
<add scheme="https" binding="wsHttpBinding" /> 
</protocolMapping>
<bindings>
<wsHttpBinding>
<binding name="secureHttpBinding">
<security mode="Transport">
<transport clientCredentialType="None" >
</transport>
</security>
</binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

I Create a Custom binding setting the messageVersion to Soap12. By this the service run on Soap1.2 but without the WS-Addressing

```
<customBinding>
<binding name="customBinding">
<textMessageEncoding messageVersion ="Soap12">
</textMessageEncoding>
<httpsTransport></httpsTransport>
```